# Xcode 5 gives error when run old projects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some problems when i am run any projects in Xcode 5 it gives error like

> Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'

[image: Image of error in ViewController]

it is happen in most of situations if i download any project from git hub or from other sources.

But if i run that project in earlier version of Xcode than its working fine.
I have tried to run it Xcode 4.6 .

here is [sample code](https://github.com/aliHafizji/MapPinClustering/archive/master.zip) that i run in Xcode 5 and gives error.

So whats problem with Xcode 5 ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180232/duplicate-interface-declaration-for-class-test-coredataappdelegate

Comment: @iPatel: download sample code that edited in question, and you will never see `include` in whole project. this is working fine in Xcode 4.6 so what happen fro xcode 5?

Comment: Does the error in the Issue Navigator (Command-4) show you where the previous definition is? (Reveal the details of the Semantic Issue error.)

Comment: @PhillipKinkade: yes it shows Semantic Issue error in issue navigation .,  I have Included project which i am running.

Comment: @Optimistic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911941/duplicate-interface-declaration-for-class-foo

Comment: @Optimistic it builds successfully for me in Xcode 5 Version 5.0.2 (5A3005).

Comment: @iPatel:check accepted answer of that, still it is un answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/3912027/2265763 , see accepted answers comments.

Comment: @PhillipKinkade: i am using Xcode 5.0, so is it bug of Xcode 5.0 ?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm not seeing the problem on my system.  I recommend that you read the details of the Semantic Issue error to find the other declaration of ViewController.

Comment: Works for me to same version as @PhillipKinkade

Comment: Thanks for your help, by mistake i have change some system header file. check my answer.

Comment: hey i am using xcode 5.0.1 n its working fine can you tell me which version you are using @Optimistic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

By some Mistake i have Change System Header file from `UIKIT > UITableViewController.h` to

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

SO in any project if there is a viewcontroller named  `ViewController` it gives this error,

So i have look in old xcode and changed it to

`NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution. You changed it to `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` Should this return an error as `UITableViewController` is already a class in `UIKit`.

Comment: @Popeye: in `UITableViewController.h` by mistake i have change `@interface UITableViewController :` to **@interface ViewController :**

Comment: Why are you even playing with that file? This is a locked file and requires a password to unlock, it should never be messed with.

Comment: As i said earlier by mistake i had changed this file.