# Command [...]/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I have a serious problem with one of my ios application because i can't compile it anymore. I think its due to a mislinked file (see the error at the end).

The whole story started when i wasn't able to add a file to a target. I then couldn't build because of this error, see: [Duplicate interface declaration for class 'Foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911941/duplicate-interface-declaration-for-class-foo). Xcode miracously copied my sources within itself to a subfolder with the projectname. I deleted as suggested but i know keep running into the error pasted at the bottom.

In effect it is due to clang looking for a file a very deeeeeeeply in itself nested folder which of course doesn't exists. What did xcode do here and how can i get it working again?

This is the last part of the error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Shared/projects/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/samefolder/AppDelegate.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found it! I knew there had to be a list of files it tries to compile somewhere. I finally found it under the targets build phases. There you have entries for "compile sources" and "copy bundle resources" which both got cluttered in my case. I corrected those file lists and it finally worked again.